# How to nest a click function inside a change function with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested

I have a select dropdown with two options: yes / no (actually three: there is also "select an option" with no value).
Then there are some chekboxes which handle some variables (when checked the variables are added to a global variable (called tot), when unckecked they are subtracted). I'd like to have two different behaviors of the checkboxes depending on if the dropdown option is yes or no. So i wrote this, but I think I'm misunderstanding/mistaking something, because it doesn't work (it works when it's not nested inside the change select function).

```
<select name="container" id="container">
<option id="none" value="" >Select an option</option>
<option id="no" value="no" >no</option>
<option id="yes" value="yes" >yes</option>
</select>
```

And here's the javascript (with jquery library)

```
var tot = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#container").change(function () {
        var sel = $(this).find(":selected").attr("id")
        if (sel == "no" || sel == "none") {

            $("#in-category-1").click(function () {
                if ($('#in-category-1').is(':checked')) {
                    if (tot < 60) {
                        tot = tot + 2.5;
                    } else if (tot >= 60) {
                        alert('Stop!');
                        $('#in-category-1').attr('checked', false);
                    }
                } else if (tot > 0) {
                    tot = tot - 2.5;
                }
                functionblablabla();
                });
                if (sel == "yes") {

                    $("#in-category-1").click(function () {
                        if ($('#in-category-1').is(':checked')) {
                            if (tot < 50) {
                                tot = tot + 2.5;
                            } else if (tot >= 50) {
                                alert('Stop!');
                                $('#in-category-1').attr('checked', false);
                            }
                        } else if (tot > 0) {
                            tot = tot - 2.5;
                        }
                        functionblablabla2();
                    });
                });
            });
```

something should happen even when options are selected by default on page load (options are stored in a database), so if no is selected the same thing should happen

```
    if (($('#no').prop('defaultSelected')) ||  ($('#none').prop('defaultSelected')) ) {
                                $("#in-category-1").click(function () {
                               //same stuff than change select no or select none
                               });
    }

    if ($('#yes').prop('defaultSelected')) {
                                $("#in-category-1").click(function () {
                               //same stuff than change select yes
                               });
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you need that sort of complex nesting. You just need to check the state of your various inputs on click to determine the action.

Comment: you mean, inside the click function I check if select option is yes or no?

Comment: Probably. I only looked at your code for a minute, but that sounds right.

Comment: the problem is: other things have to happen on the change function. for example, is yes is selected after tot variable is already over 60 the the option is automatically switched to none (with an alert). anyway maybe you're right, I'll try something like that.

Comment: I tried with `defaultSelected` and doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Some points you can do better:

- brackets

  - looks like the 'if yes' should be part of the large if block
  - missing some closing ones
- don't create global VARs

  - put the 'tod' var in the dom ready function
- detach the previous click events (otherwise the events will sume up if the options are changed more than once)

  `$("#in-category-1").off("click");`
- get the selected value with the shortcut

  `$(this).val();`

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kmybV/